# Cross Device Tracking Without Login Info

Tags: javascript, html, analytics, user-tracking, fingerprinting

I have been working on a project to identify users from different devices. I know it is not mature to ask such a question here. I know its scope are very big. Any way I like to start a discussion here. I am sure that i can get points that helps me find points.

I believe everybody know about cross device tracking. It may be the holy grail of future ad marketing. I would like to create a system that can identify unique users even if they use different devices. I know little about IP zoning, device fingerprint, behaviour data. But not much details is available. Please give some points that help me.

Comment: Try This: http://codingresource.blogspot.in/2010/02/get-client-mac-address-ip-address-using.html

Comment: tks amy. But it require much more permissions. Not works on a general web